# How can set global font-family using Styled-Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I want to set the `font-family` globally using `Styled-Components`. I used `createGlobalStyle` and set font to body, but the divs inside the body didn't inherit the font.

Here is my Styled-components body:

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';

export const AppRoot = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    @import url('../../font.css');
    font-family: Vazir !important;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    cursor: default;
  }
`;
```

And here is how I use it:

```
import {AppRoot} from './StyledComponents';

ReactDOM.render (
  <Fragment>
    <AppRoot/>
    <App />
  </Fragment>,
  document.getElementById ('root')
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do like this with `*` selector instead of `body`.

```
export default createGlobalStyle`
        * {
            @import url('../../font.css');
            font-family: Vazir !important;
            // CSS you want global. 
        }
    
`
```

I used it to create a reset css to remove some browser's rules.

Comment: how would I do this if I'm using @font-face { ... }

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to overwrite the value with exact format

In browser, the default style sheet mentioned the font in font shorthand format. Try to give the font in below format and let me know whether it is works.

```
 font: italic small-caps normal 13px/150% Vazir;
```